# Probability of something happening before something else happens

Tags: probability, statistics

I have a problem, where I have given a certain time, and rates at which two different events ($\text{event}\space 1$ and $\text{event}\space 2$) happen on average (they don't HAVE to happen, though).

What I want to know is the probability that in the given time $\text{event}\space 1$ happens, but $\text{event}\space 1$ has not yet happened (...at the time $\text{case}\space 1$ happens. I don't care about what happens after $\text{case}\space 1$ has happened)

Example values are:

$\text{time} = 330s$

$r_{\text{event 1}} = 3\times10^{-6} s^{-1}$ (probability for $\text{event 1}$ to happen during $1$ sec = $3\times10^{-6}$)

$r_{\text{event 2}} = 5\times10^{-6} s^{-1}$ (probability for $\text{event 1}$ to happen during $1$ sec = $5\times10^{-6}$)

What is the probability that in the given 330s event 1 happens, without event 2 having happened first?

thanks in advance!

Comment: You need information regarding the dependence of two events.

Comment: the dependence on what? I don't think I have much else given. It is actually a chemistry problem for a given molecule. I have rates at which the molecules break apart and at which the molecules are being ionized. I am not sure how the two rates / probabilities are connected. 
(The final goal I want is to know what the chance is that my molecule is being ionized before it falls apart.)

Comment: $$P(\text{event 2}\le330s)=\sum_{i=0}^{329} (1-3\times10^{-6})^i\cdot3\times10^{-6}\\P(\text{event 1}>330s)=\sum_{i=0}^{330}(1-5\times10^{-6})^i$$If they are independent, you can just multiply these probabilities

Comment: On each other!  For all your readers know, event $2$ might refer to the second instance of event $1$ in the same second.  In that case the answer would be $1$.  Also, we need to know if each second is independent of the other seconds.

Comment: I am not familiar with the relevant chemistry, but those two events sure do not sound independent.  If I am right about that, this is a Chemistry question, not a Math question.

Comment: ok. I would have thought that the rates are completely independent. Would there be a simple mathematical solution for that?

Comment: thank you, John Doe. I thought of that, but your solution requires that event 1 does not happen during the 330s. In my problem, event 1 MAY happen, just not before event 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From reading the comments, it seems like you want $$\begin{align}\sum_{n=1}^{330}P(\text{event 2}=n\le330,\text{event 1}>n)&=\sum_{n=1}^{330}\left[(1-3\times10^{-6})^{n-1}\cdot3\times10^{-6}\right]\left[(1-5\times10^{-6})^n\right]\\&=\frac{3\times10^{-6}}{1-3\times10^{-6}}\sum_{n=1}^{330}\left[(1-3\times10^{-6})(1-5\times10^{-6})\right]^n\end{align}$$ You can evaluate the sum using a geometric sum formula.

Comment: This looks perfect! Thank you!